# Create a alarm to notify when ip addresses are running low

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is there any way to create a alarm in AWS for ip-addresses are about to running out?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "IP address about to run out"? What IP addresses are you referring to? Private IP addresses within a particular VPC subnet, or Elastic IP addresses, or something else?

Comment: private ip adresses in a subnet.

Comment: i can create a lambda that reports avaible ip's and do a metric based on that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard Amazon CloudWatch alarm for monitoring available IP addresses in a subnet. However, you could:

- Create an AWS Lambda function that scans the subnet(s) and sends a **custom metric** to CloudWatch
- Create an **Amazon CloudWatch Events rule** that triggers the Lambda function at a desired interval
- Create an **Alarm** on the custom metric to notify you when the metric drops below a desired level

The benefit of this approach is that you will **retain a history**, within the custom metric, of the number of available IP addresses. However, it would involve a separate custom metric and alarm for each subnet.

Alternatively, you could configure the Lambda function to **send a message to an Amazon SNS topic** whenever there is a low quantity of IP addresses in a subnet. Then, subscribe to the SNS topic to receive notification. While there is no history available, it requires less configuration because it doesn't use CloudWatch.

Comment: Thanks! Will try this.

Comment: Here you are a detailed implementation: https://plippe.github.io/blog/2019/07/01/monitoring-aws-ip-availability.html